# How do you convert these nested foreach to linq

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Here is my query with nested foreach:

```
foreach (Order order in xOrders)
{
    foreach (OrderItemDetail oid in order.OrderItemDetails)
    {
        db.Entry(oid).Reload();
    }

    foreach (Dispatch dispatch in order.Dispatches)
    {
        foreach (DispatchItemDetail did in dispatch.DispatchItemDetails)
        {
            db.Entry(did).Reload();
        }

        db.Entry(dispatch).Reload();
    }

    db.Entry(order).Reload();
}
```

Now, I want to convert that to pure linq, so I am safer atleast for the errors such as Enumeration cannot continue because Collection was changed.

I know, if there is 1 foreach I can convert it to LINQ like:

foreach query:

```
foreach (Order order in xOrders)
{
    db.Entry(order).Reload();
}
```

LINQ query:

```
xOrders.ToList().ForEach(x => db.Entry(x).Reload());
```

But I want to know how you can do that for Nested foreach as shown in the first code block....

Comment: Other than the `ToList` that is not `LINQ`, `ForEach` is a method on `List<T>`. Linq is for querying data, not modifying data.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the concept. But can you please tell me how can I use ForEach in this case??

Comment: Why would you want to, the way you had it orginally is much more clear. Also, any LINQ version will be slower due to all the extra memory used up by the `.ToList()` calls you will have to make.

Comment: "*Here is my query with nested foreach*" This is not a query at all. The code should stay as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ForEach takes a delegate as a parameter. So you can write static method or anonymous function. I'm writing with Anonymus method. But the way you do above is the best way than using ForEach()

```
 xOrders.ToList().ForEach((x) => {
     x.OrderItemDetails.ToList().ForEach(o => db.Entry(o).Reload());
     x.Dispatches.ToList().ForEach((D) => {
       D.DispatchItemDetails.ToList().ForEach(DI => db.Entry(DI).Reload());
       db.Entry(D).Reload();
     });
     db.Entry(x).Reload();
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. Your code gave me error, then I just changed it and updated in your answer. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: It looks like a mess, it degrades performance, it increases memory usage. I don't understand why anyone wants to code like this.

Comment: Yes, @hazevich you are right. This degrades the performance. But I just give the answer for learning purpose. I also mentioned that it is not the right way.

Comment: @hazevich I got many errors regarding enumeration cannot be used as collection was changed. So, I am now changing foreach to this syntax.

Comment: @Vishal so? you got rid of the exception, because `ForEach()` internally uses `for` loop, but how does it code gonna save you from a race condition? Which is the root of your problem?

Comment: @Vishal what I'm trying to say is that you got rid of your symtomps, but there's no cure. If you have some code which can change your collection in some another thread you should consider yourself to make some thread synchronization. For example with simple locking, i.e. locking your collection while you're doing your `Reload()`. Because in some case you might have a code which will remove some element from your collection and then in `ForEach()` you'll get the `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

Comment: @hazevich I will try it as you suggested. I would use locking and interlocking concepts instead of ForEach whereever necessary.